# aws-cli 2 permission denied error in linux after installation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Getting `permission denied error` after installing aws-cli version using the [official AWS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html) while running `aws --version`

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fix to this issue would be to provide the right set of file permissions to aws-cli.

```
which aws            # Find the path of aws-cli, say /usr/local/aws-cli/

sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/aws-cli/
```

Answer (score 0):

What helped me here was I wasn't following the AWS provided instructions exactly. I tried curl-ing the .zip file into a different directory and unzipping it from there. The .zip file needs to be in the root directory for proper installation. FWIW I was installing using a Dockerfile with an Ubuntu Jammy base image.